# Ruby: How to refactor very similar classes?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I've got a bunch of classes that are very similar to each other. The only difference is in a part of the class name, some pathes, and other classes that call, that belong in the same group.

So for example I have a XDispatcher which uses a XImporter, and a YDispatcher which uses a YImporter, where the Dispatchers and Importers are identical save for the names and any fragment using the name, such as pathes, calls to other classes of that grouping.

```
class XDispatcher
  def initialize
    path = Rails.root.join('x_dispatcher/files')
  end

  def run
    # do stuff
    # importer = XImporter.new()
  end
end

class YDispatcher
  def initialize
    path = Rails.root.join('y_dispatcher/files')
  end

  def run
    # do stuff
    importer = YImporter.new()
  end
end
```

EDIT:
Shame on me..I totally blended out inheritance and extension. In order to keep this question interesting, I would like to see some fancy stuff or experimental ways to solve this 'problem'.

Comment: Create a `Dispatcher` class and have `XDispatcher` and `YDispatcher` be subclasses?

Comment: Damn, how on earth could I have missed that? Totally blended out inheritence and extension of classes. Let's spice the question up then: is it possible without inheritence/extension? With some metaprogramming maybe?

Comment: If these are that close (limited basically to what you're showing) then you could have a `Dispatcher` class and have the `initialize` handle the difference via an argument at creation and make a generic `Importer` that is configured depending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only difference is a name, you shouldn't even bother with inheritance. Just initialize your Dispatcher with a name and then pass it where you need it:

```
class Dispatcher
  def initialize name
    @name = name
    path = Rails.root.join("#{@name}_dispatcher/files")
  end

  def run
    # do stuff
    # importer = Importer.new(@name)
  end
end

Dispatcher.new("x").run
Dispatcher.new("y").run
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was aiming for.

Comment: `Dispatcher.new("X").run` will produce a path of `X_dispatcher/files` which is different to `x_dispatcher/files`. I think you should change the examples to `Dispatcher.new("x").run` and `Dispatcher.new("y").run`

Comment: You could buy some generality and neatness by passing a second argument to `initialize`, namely, `dispatcher_files`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like this.

```
class Dispatcher
  def initialize
    path = Rails.root.join(self.class::RAILS_ROOT_PATH)
  end

  def run
    # do stuff
    importer = self.class::IMPORTER_CLASS.new
    # process
  end
end

class XDispatcher < Dispatcher
  RAILS_ROOT_PATH = 'x_dispatcher/files'
  IMPORTER_CLASS = XImporter
end

class YDispatcher < Dispatcher
  RAILS_ROOT_PATH = 'y_dispatcher/files'
  IMPORTER_CLASS = YImporter
end
```

Comment: You don't have to do `self.class.const_get(:IMPORTER_CLASS).new` if `IMPORTER_CLASS` is holding the class itself

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
class Dispatcher
  class << self
     attr_accessor :file_path, importer_class
  end

  def path 
    @path ||= Rails.root.join(self.class.file_path)
  end

  def importer
    @importer ||= self.class.importer_class.new
  end

  def run
    # do stuff
  end
end

class XDispatcher < Dispatcher
  file_path = 'x_dispatcher/files'
  importer_class = XImporter
end

class YDispatcher < Dispatcher
  file_path = 'y_dispatcher/files'
  importer_class = YImporter
end
```

Two main reasons:

1. It removes the reliance on constants - and particularly the issue of them not being present in the parent class - or if they are, them being overwritten in the child class
2. It removes the reliance on the `initialize` method needing to have to do more than load initial data - which [in my opinion is bad practice](http://nicholshayes.co.uk/blog/?p=267)